# Transfer Function of Spring-Damper System

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, springs, transfer-function, stability

Given the spring-damper system below where $x_i$, $x_i$, and $y_i$ are position values, how do I find the transfer function $\frac{X_o(s)}{X_i(s)}$? Wouldn't it require mass? I tried neglecting the masses in the equation but it zeros out the acceleration term and does not work. Any diea?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a HW problem. In order to seek help from this community you need to show your work. So what have you done so far, show work

Comment: That's a very odd looking naming convention...  I'm not sure why it goes $x_i$, $x_0$ and then $y$ when they all seem to be different masses with the same direction of displacement.  The $y$, $x_o$ and $x_i$ should all be masses though (at least the diagram implies that).

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena I'm simply asking about the masses, I'm not asking for a solution because I'll solve it on my own. Should I assign mass numbers to the squares in between the spring or damper branches? Are they supposed to be masses? Can the problem be even solved if there are no masses?

Comment: @JMac I'm sure the naming y is random and bears no significance with the system's orientation relative to displacements $x_o$ and $x_i$. So the squares in between the spring/damper branches are indeed implied to be masses right? The masses can't be zero right?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Besides, I have tried solving the problem assuming no masses and I couldn't get a transfer function. So I'm asking if there really should be masses or if it's possible to solve that system assuming no masses.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume they all represent masses.  Technically you could probably have one or two count as massless, then it would be like multiple springs & dampers in parallel (they could all be massless but then I don't know if it's even a dynamic system anymore, or just theoretical nothingness, since there would be no resistance to force; you couldn't even really define energies or potential energies or anything).  Whenever I've seen systems like that with blocks labelled as reference points it's generally because they are a mass we are concerned with.

Comment: @JMac Thanks a lot!! Thant answers my question.

Comment: If there are no masses, the differential equation of motion in the time domain is first order not second order. There is no problem converting that into the frequency domain and finding a transfer function, but you can't just "plug and chug" a method that only works for 2nd order equations!

Answer (score 2):

First, create the free body diagram for this system. If you cut through the spring $k_1$ and the damper $b_1$ you will get two forces $F_{k_1}=k_1(x_i-x_0)$ and $F_{b_1}=b_1(\dot{x}_i-\dot{x}_0)$ opposing the direction of $x_i$. Writing down Newton's second law of motion for the mass $m_i$ will result in:

$$m_i\ddot{x}_i=-b_1(\dot{x}_i-\dot{x}_0)-k_1(x_i-x_0) \implies m_i\ddot{x}_i+b_1\dot{x}_i+k_1x_i=b_1\dot{x}_0+k_1x_0.$$

Assuming zero initial conditions we can transform this into the Laplace domain:

$$\left[m_is^2+b_1s+k_1\right]x_i(s)=\left[b_1s+k_1\right]x_0 \implies \frac{x_0(s)}{x_i(s)}=\frac{m_is^2+b_1s+k_1}{b_1s+k_1}.$$

If the point $x_i$ is attached to a massless position, then we simply set $m_i=0$ in the previous expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem has the following structure:

- $y$ corresponds to the disturbance from the road
- $x_o$ corresponds to the travel of the unsprung mass
- $x_i$ corresponds to the travel of the sprung mass

This is in accordance to this image.

[image]

For this problem, I think masses should be assigned to displacement $x_o$ and $x_i$. Otherwise there is not much point.